# Defined functions in structures in SML results in "value type in structure does not match signature spec"

Tags: sml, smlnj

It has been quite a while since I've been programming in SML and now I'm stuck on what looks to me a very simple issue.

I'm defining a `datatype` like

```
datatype 'a Something = Something of 'a
```

then I'm defining a `signature` as follows

```
signature A = sig
  val some : 'a -> 'a -> 'a Something
end
```

the `structure` implementing that `signature` instead looks like this

```
structure B : A = struct
  fun some(a) = fn x => if a=x then Something a else Something x
end
```

That end up producing the following error and I don't understand why

```
Error: value type in structure does not match signature spec
  name: some
spec:   'a -> 'a -> 'a Something
actual: ''a -> ''a -> ''a Something
```

If I define the structure as follows instead

```
structure C : A = struct
  fun some(a) = fn x => Something a
end
```

everything works smoothly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When I try your code, I do not get this error. I am using sosml.org as installing SML tools of any kind on this PC has proven impractical.

Comment: I'm having that error both with smlnj and mosml and, same as you, on sosml.org works. That's what I don't fully get. Is it supposed to work or not?

Comment: I suspect that sosml.org is not very standard-compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TLDR:

The type variable `'a` doesn't support equality comparison. You need an "equality type variable" instead. These are written with two leading apostrophes, i.e. `''a`. Here's the fixed code. Both SML/NJ and MLton accept it.

```ml
datatype ''a Something = Something of ''a
signature A = sig
  val some : ''a -> ''a -> ''a Something
end
structure B : A = struct
  fun some(a) = fn x => if a=x then Something a else Something x
end
```

An alternative solution is continue using `'a`, and explicitly pass around a function to test for equality.

```ml
datatype 'a Something = Something of 'a
signature A = sig
  (* first arg is equality function *)
  val some : ('a * 'a -> bool) -> 'a -> 'a -> 'a Something
end
structure B : A = struct
  fun some eq a = fn x => if eq (a, x) then Something a else Something x
end
```

## Details

The equality test `if a=x then ... else ...` is attempting to check for equality between two values of type `'a`.

The problem is that not all possible instantiations of `'a` support equality tests.

For example, what if you wanted to do `B.some (fn i => i) (fn i => 2*i)`? This instantiates `'a` with the concrete type `int -> int`. Your code now wants to attempt to perform an equality comparison between the functions `fn i => i` and `fn i => 2*i`, but SML doesn't know how to compare functions for equality.

To work around this problem, SML has a... somewhat hacky solution. It distinguishes between two kinds of polymorphism: types that support equality, and types that do not.

Normal type variables are written with a single apostrophe (`'a`, `'b`, `'whatever`, etc.), and these do not allow for polymorphic equality.

Equality type variables are written with two apostrophes (`''a`, `''b`, etc.), and these allow for polymorphic equality.

Equality type variables are more restrictive than normal type variables.

See http://mlton.org/PolymorphicEquality for more info!